# How can I create a list of buttons in ListView builder that coincide with the labels next to them in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make this app that displays a list of historical figures using ListView in flutter. So far I have been able to make the list of names of historical figures. My next task is to make a button for each historical figure that goes next to the name, which would bring you to another screen with information about that specific historical figure. This is what I have so far and I'm having trouble implementing a button next to the historical figures name. I've tried making a class with IconButton but don't know how to route it/keep getting an error and also with IconButton how would I make a list of buttons that concide with name next to them. Open to any ideas. Thanks.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "historicalfigureinfo.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Hwk3()));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/':(context) => const Hwk3(),
        '/SantosDumont':(context)=>SantosDumont(),
        '/PabloPicasso':(context)=>PabloPicasso(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Hwk3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hwk3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Hwk3State createState() => _Hwk3State();
}

class _Hwk3State extends State<Hwk3> {
  var nameArray = [
    'Abraham Lincoln',
    'Benito Juarez',
    'Claude Monet',
    'Charles Darwin',
    'Deng Xiaoping',
    'Frederick Chopin',
    'George Washington Carver',
    'Georgia O\'Keeffe',
    'Mahatma Gandhi',
    'Mark Twain',
    'Muhammad Jinnah',
    'Pablo Picasso',
    'Santos Dumont'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Historical Figures'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(nameArray[index]),
              trailing: InfoButtons(historicalfigure: '/SantosDumont'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfoButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final String historicalfigure;

  InfoButtons({required this.historicalfigure});
  //Hector Merejo
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        tooltip: "Press for more information on historical figure",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(historicalfigure);
        }));
  }
}
```

This is the error I get with the code above. Also I get this error if I click on any of the buttons next to the names. I would think I should get this error only when I click on Santos Dumont and nothing should happen if I click on the other names.

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/SantosDumont", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

Sorry if my explanation is confusing. Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `home` parameter if your using named routing. That is causing the problem. See the relevant doc. [Flutter doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..... this post helped [Page routing using List index in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112740/page-routing-using-list-index-in-flutter)

```
class _Hwk3State extends State<Hwk3> {
  var nameArray = [
    'Abraham Lincoln',
    'Benito Juarez',
    'Claude Monet',
    'Charles Darwin',
    'Deng Xiaoping',
    'Frederick Chopin',
    'George Washington Carver',
    'Georgia O\'Keeffe',
    'Mahatma Gandhi',
    'Mark Twain',
    'Muhammad Jinnah',
    'Pablo Picasso',
    'Santos Dumont'
  ];
  List<Route> historicalfigures= [
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AbrahamLincoln()),
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => BenitoJuarez()),
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ClaudeMonet()),
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CharlesDarwin()),
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DengXiaoping()),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Route> myRoute = [];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Historical Figures'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(nameArray[index]),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.info_outlined),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(historicalfigures[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still, there is an error in your main function.  You created those routes and they never called. I posted an answer you can check it over there.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by never called. This code works but only once then it throws an error. I'm not using the InfoButton class anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is your main function. When you use named routing, do not use `home` property in `MaterialApp`. Also, in your function you are calling for `Hwk3` class, not the `MyApp` class, that's why the routes are never called in `MaterialApp`.

This class is never used

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/':(context) => const Hwk3(),
        '/SantosDumont':(context)=>SantosDumont(),
        '/PabloPicasso':(context)=>PabloPicasso(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In your main function, you're not calling for ***actual*** `MaterialApp`. You are calling for `Hwk3` class.

```
runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Hwk3()));
```

So, you can copy the following code.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "historicalfigureinfo.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(

      MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/':(context) => const Hwk3(),
          '/SantosDumont':(context)=>SantosDumont(),
          '/PabloPicasso':(context)=>PabloPicasso(),
        },
      )
  );
}
class Hwk3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hwk3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Hwk3State createState() => _Hwk3State();
}

class _Hwk3State extends State<Hwk3> {
  var nameArray = [
    'Abraham Lincoln',
    'Benito Juarez',
    'Claude Monet',
    'Charles Darwin',
    'Deng Xiaoping',
    'Frederick Chopin',
    'George Washington Carver',
    'Georgia O\'Keeffe',
    'Mahatma Gandhi',
    'Mark Twain',
    'Muhammad Jinnah',
    'Pablo Picasso',
    'Santos Dumont'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Historical Figures'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(nameArray[index]),
              trailing: InfoButtons(historicalfigure: '/SantosDumont'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfoButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final String historicalfigure;

  InfoButtons({required this.historicalfigure});
  //Hector Merejo
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        tooltip: "Press for more information on historical figure",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(historicalfigure);
        }));
  }
}
```